# AS2: string in array is undefined

Tags: arrays, actionscript, multidimensional-array, actionscript-2, undefined

I have the following code on the timeline, but when I try and output `date_string` from the `Slider_Tracker` array it says it is undefined.

```
var Days:Array = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday');
var Months:Array = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
var current_date = new Date();
var day_num = current_date.getDay();
var year = current_date.getFullYear();
var month = current_date.getMonth();
var date_num:String = new String(current_date.getDate());
date_char = date_num.charAt(date_num.length-1);
if (date_char == 1) {
    date_suffix = "st";
}
else if (date_char == 2) {
    date_suffix = "nd";
}
else if (date_char == 3) {
    date_suffix = "rd";
}
var date_string:String = new String(Days[day_num]+" "+date_num+date_suffix+" of "+Months[month]+" "+year);
trace(date_string);
date_int = current_date.getTime();
trace(current_date);
trace(date_int);
var Sliders:Array = Array (slider1.slider, slider2.slider, slider3.slider, slider4.slider, slider5.slider, slider6.slider, slider7.slider, slider8.slider, slider9.slider);
var Slide_Tracker:Array = new Array();
var local_data = SharedObject.getLocal("user_data");

if (local_data.data.user_data == undefined) {
    local_data.data.user_data = Slide_Tracker;
    trace("fail");
} else {
    Slide_Tracker = local_data.data.user_data;
    for (i=0;i<Slide_Tracker.length;i++) {
            trace(Slide_Tracker[i][1]);

        if(Slide_Tracker[i][1] == date_string) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    trace("success");
}
var current_time = new Date();

this._parent.fullClear.onRelease = function() {
    local_data.clear();
}

this._parent.saver.onRelease = function() {
trace(date_string);
Slide_Tracker.push(new Array(date_int, date_string));
for (i=0;i<Sliders.length;i++) {
    Slide_Tracker[0].push(100-Sliders[i]._y);
}
    Slide_tracker.push(today_Stats);
    local_data.data.user_data = Slide_Tracker;
    local_data.flush();

    nextFrame();

};
```

Can anyone see my downfall? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the `trace` in `this._parent.saver.onRelease`?

That's a different scope unfortunately, it'll be relative to your `this._parent.saver` MovieClip, so it won't have access to `date_string` and `Slide_Tracker` you defined here.

Comment: that trace works, above where I select Slide_Tracker[i][1] (which is where date_string is stored) they output undefineds. If I trace the whole array same story everything is stored fine except for date_string which is undefined. (date_int is stored fine).

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry for the wrong input. Do you get those slider values back stored with this line: `Slide_Tracker[0].push(100-Sliders[i]._y);`?

Comment: Yeh it does, ignore my other comment (now deleted) it isn't working, the value is correctly stored in the array but when you close reopen and grab the sharedobject the string is now undefined.

Comment: Hmm, that might be a shared object serialisation / deserialisation issue, can you do a full trace of what you get back?

Comment: Sure... Input: `1307027496434,Thursday 2nd of June 2011,29,60,33,30,55,25,25,25,25` Output: `1307027496434,undefined,29,60,33,30,55,25,25,25,25`

Comment: That is very strange... Anyway, what I'd do is to change the `Slide_Tracker` to be an `Object` instead of an `Array` and store these different bits as properly typed (`Number`, `String`, `Array`), named properties

Comment: Genius! never used objects properly before but it suits my needs even better and retains the string value, I still store the objects in an array.